# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \pi/4} (2\sin(x)-\sqrt{2})/(\tan(x)-1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \pi/4} (2\sin(x)-\sqrt{2})/(\tan(x)-1)$$

I came across this limit and I got stuck. I used L'Hopital's rule and I got $1/\sqrt{2}$.

But what I want to know is if there is any other way (transformation rules) to compute the limit?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please refer [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I would change variable $t = x -\frac{\pi}4$ and then use addition formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply and divide by $x-\pi/4$:$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{2\sin(x)-\sqrt{2}}{\tan(x)-1}
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{2\sin(x)-\sqrt{2}}{x-\pi/4}\cdot \frac{x-\pi/4}{\tan(x)-1}
$$This is the limit definition of the derivative.
$$
= \left(\left.\frac{d}{dx}2\sin(x)\right|_{x=\pi/4}\right)/\left(\left.\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x)\right|_{x=\pi/4}\right)
$$
$$
=  \sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!